# Lucene.Net persisting boost values

Tags: c#, search, lucene.net, lucene

I have an Index created but it has lot of junk data. What I hope to accomplish is a voting system, where more votes equates to a higher boost value. Unfortunately the boost values are not saved back to the index after user submits a vote.

This is the breakdown of the code for my Boost function, does anyone have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? I used explain(), but it doesn't have anything related to the boost value.

```
BoostUp(int documentId)
{


    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(dir);

    Document oldDoc = search.doc(documentId);
    //get all the stored information from old document

    Document updatedDocument = new Document();
    //Add fields containing data from old document.

    updatedDocument.Boost = oldDoc.Boost * 1.5F;

    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30), false, MaxFieldLength.LIMITED);

    Term uniqueTerm = new term("content_id", content_id_from_old_document);

    writer.UpdateDocument(uniqueTerm, updatedDocument);
    writer.Commit();
    writer.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you can't retrieve that value from the index.  The retrieved document doesn't have the boost set.  It is combined with other index-time scoring factors and encoded in the index such that it is not possible to retrieve it.

The solution, I think, would be to save the boost as a field stored in the index, and retrieve that, and use it to modify and set the boost.

Something along these lines:

```
Field boostField = oldDoc.getField("saved_boost");
float newBoost = boostField.numericValue().floatValue() * 1.5F;
updatedDocument.setBoost(newBoost);
updatedDocument.removeField("saved_boost");
NumericField boostField = new NumericField("saved_boost",Field.Store.YES,false);
boostField.setFloatValue(newBoost);
updatedDocument.add(boostField);

//No changes from here on...

IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30), false, MaxFieldLength.LIMITED);

Term uniqueTerm = new term("content_id", content_id_from_old_document);

writer.UpdateDocument(uniqueTerm, updatedDocument);
```

Comment: I did not expect that, great workaround. Thanks!! [Link to documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/Document.html#getBoost())